# Euler-Cromer ODE Python Routine

Tags: python, python-2.7, ode

I am using an Euler-Cromer scheme to calculate the position and velocity of Halley's comet. The script tries several values for a time-step (tau) for each value of initial velocity in a range. For each tau value, it runs through the Euler-Cromer routine and compares the total mechanical energy from the beginning of the orbit to the end of the first orbit's cycle. If the percent difference between the two energies is less than 1%, the current (optimal) value of tau is added to a list. After all the iterations, the values of tau and initial velocities are plotted using pyplot on a semi-log graph so that the true initial velocity of Halley's comet can be interpreted. However, each element of my optimal taus list is the first element of my tau range (currently 0.1). The script seems more complex than necessary and perhaps a bit convoluted. Here it is:
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

```
## Set physical parameters and initial position and velocity of the comet
GM = 4 * np.pi ** 2             # Grav const. times mass of sun (AU^3/yr^2)
mass = 1.                       # Mass of comet
r0 = 35                         # Initial aphelion position
v0 = np.arange(0.5, 1.1, 0.1)   # Create a range of initial velocities in AU/year


## Function that takes position and velocity vectors and the initial total energy
## and outputs the value of tau that provides a less than 1% error in the total energy
def tau_test(vel):
    tau = np.arange(.1, .009, -.001)
    r = [r0, 0]
    v = vel
    optimal_tau = 0
    for t in tau:
        i = 0
        i_max = 5 * 76 / t
        r_mag_initial = np.sqrt(r[0] ** 2 + r[1] ** 2)      # initial magnitude of the position vector
        v_mag_initial = np.sqrt(v[0] ** 2 + v[1] ** 2)      # initial magnitude of the velocity vector
        KE_initial = 0.5 * mass * v_mag_initial ** 2        # initial kinetic energy
        PE_initial = -GM * mass / r_mag_initial             # initial potential energy
        ME_initial = KE_initial + PE_initial                # initial total energy
        ## Main looping function (using Euler-Cromer method for now)
        while not i == i_max:
            r_mag = np.sqrt(r[0] ** 2 + r[1] ** 2)      # magnitude of the position vector
            v_mag_a = np.sqrt(v[0] ** 2 + v[1] ** 2)    # current velocity magnitude
            a = [-GM * r[0] / r_mag ** 3,               # acceleration vector
                 -GM * r[1] / r_mag ** 3]               # based on the current position
            v = [v[0] + t * a[0], v[1] + t * a[1]]      # new velocity vector using Euler-Cromer method
            r = [r[0] + t * v[0], r[1] + t * v[1]]      # new position vector using Euler-Cromer method
            v_mag_b = np.sqrt(v[0] ** 2 + v[1] ** 2)    # new velocity magnitude
            if i > .75 * 76 / t:                        # Ensure that the comet is at least past the sun
                if v_mag_b > v_mag_a:                   # Break out of the while loop if the comet is starting
                    break                               # to move back toward the sun
            i += 1
        v_mag = np.sqrt(v[0] ** 2 + v[1] ** 2)          # final magnitude of the velocity vector
        r_mag = np.sqrt(r[0] ** 2 + r[1] ** 2)          # final magnitude of the position vector
        KE = 0.5 * mass * v_mag ** 2                    # final kinetic energy
        PE = -GM * mass / r_mag                         # final potential energy
        ME = KE + PE                                    # final total energy
        #print ME
        if abs(((ME - ME_initial) / ME_initial) * 100) <= 1:    # If the percent error between the initial and final
            optimal_tau = t                                     # total energies is less than 1%, set t as the optimal
            break                                               # tau and break out of the for loop
    return optimal_tau

## Loop through each initial velocity and test it against several values of tau
taus = []
for u in v0:
    v = [0, u]
    #print ME_initial
    taus.append(tau_test(v))

#print taus
## Plot the values of tau and initial velocity on a semi-log graph
## so that the true velocity of Halley's comet can be interpreted
plt.semilogy(v0, taus)
plt.grid(True)
plt.title('Tau versus Initial Velocities')

plt.show()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: My question is: why doesn't the script find the optimal value of tau for each initial velocity as I expect?

Comment: You yourself admit that the script is too complex and convoluted. For better chance of an answer isolate where the problem and post THAT as the question; use a debugger to help you with this. Click on "Help" at the top of this page to see how to write a question that is likely to get answers.

Comment: You are right, I was asking too-general of a question. I am no longer using the above script, so I am closing this question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of banging my head against the wall, I decided to go back to my original scrip that plots the trajectory of the comet and its energy over time. I edited it to find the percent difference between the initial total energy and the total energy of the comet after each orbit. I plotted the total energy percent difference trend and simply reran the program several times, using different time step values for each initial velocity between 0.3 and 1. While this was essentially a brute-force solution, it worked.